# How can I render mixed-colour text in DirectWrite?

Tags: directwrite

I want to use DirectWrite for mixed-colour text formatting (syntax highlighting, to be precise), but can't seem to find a way to do it, either in the Layout or Typography options. The only option is passing a Brush when rendering the text, which doesn't work for me because I basically have just one Layout. Help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `IDWriteTextLayout::SetDrawingEffect` to apply drawing effects on subranges. If you're using DWrite with D2D `DrawTextLayout`, which it sounds like you are, then that drawing effect would just be a brush (such as `ID2D1Brush` via `CreateSolidColorBrush` or one of the gradient brushes). If you have implemented your own `IDWriteTextRenderer` for `IDWriteTextLayout::Draw`, then the drawing effect can be whatever you interpret it to be. In the `IDWriteTextRenderer::DrawGlyphRun` callback, you then call `QueryInterface` on the drawingEffect parameter, or if you are certain it is your own type, just static_cast it directly.

```
// ... create the colored brushes and determine where to draw ...
wchar_t const* text = L"Red Green";
dwriteFactory->CreateTextLayout(....., OUT &textLayout);

DWRITE_TEXT_RANGE textRange1 = {0,3}, textRange2 = {4,5};

textLayout->SetDrawingEffect(redBrush,  textRange1);
textLayout->SetDrawingEffect(greenBrush, textRange2);

renderer->DrawTextLayout(point, textLayout, defaultBrush);
```