# Why does DrawTextLayout ignore brushes from SetDrawingEffect in SharpDX?

Tags: c#, sharpdx, directwrite

My goal is to draw text in a single layout with certain ranges different sizes and opacities.
The [`ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371913.aspx) method seems to be the way to go.

The documentation for the `defaultForegroundBrush` parameter:

> The brush used to paint any text in textLayout that does not already
>   have a brush associated with it as a drawing effect (specified by the
>   [IDWriteTextLayout::SetDrawingEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371477.aspx) method).

According to the Remarks section of the [`IDWriteTextLayout::SetDrawingEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371477.aspx) method,

> An [ID2D1Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371173.aspx), such as a color or gradient brush, can be set as a
>   drawing effect if you are using the [ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371913.aspx)
>   to draw text and that brush will be used to draw the specified range
>   of text.
>
> This drawing effect is associated with the specified range and will be
>   passed back to the application by way of the callback when the range
>   is drawn at drawing time.

It sounds like `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout` will definitely use any brush set by `IDWriteTextLayout::SetDrawingEffect`. This [unmanaged C++ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7370395/521757) seems to corroborate this idea.

However, in practice, `DrawTextLayout` ignores any `SolidColorBrush` I set using `SetDrawingEffect`. I get styles and sizes in the appropriate ranges, but everything is painted using the default brush.

I worked around this by implementing a custom text renderer ([gist](https://gist.github.com/jnm2/a067c444fac9d5b34298)) which is dead simple and drew exactly what I expected from `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout` as per the documentation. I would have been satisfied but the performance of a `TextRendererBase` and `DrawGlyphRun` are more than 25% slower than `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout`.

What might be causing this issue? Can I use color as the documentation suggests and still use `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawTextLayout`?

Comment: Found and fixed a memory leak ([see new link](https://gist.github.com/jnm2/a067c444fac9d5b34298)).

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar and am very interested in your answer jnm2, would you be able to give an example usage of your CustomBrushTextRenderer class?  I don't have a C++ background so have been struggling with the native DirectX docs on this.

Comment: @millejos usage is replacing `renderTarget.DrawTextLayout(params);` with `CustomBrushTextRenderer.DrawTextLayout(renderTarget, params);`- does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.  One more really quick question?  Is it possible to pass a custom class to TextLayout.SetDrawingEffect()? (instead of a color)  I basically want to pass two colors, and use them to render a shadow for the text. [more here if you're interested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311969/sharpdx-advanced-text-rendering-multibrush), otherwise thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond me. I believe you can use any class and it's up to the renderer to decide what to do with the custom class as you can see [I did](https://gist.github.com/jnm2/a067c444fac9d5b34298#file-custombrushtextrenderer-cs-L16) with the not-supposed-to-be-custom effect (brush). In other words, I'd expect a custom effect only to be recognized by a custom renderer that was checking for it. I don't know DirectX but it looks like only one effect is possible at a time, so you'd have to combine the shadow and forecolor effects into one effect class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
layout.SetDrawingEffect(myBrush, new TextRange(1, 5));
```

call it like this:

```
layout.SetDrawingEffect(myBrush.NativePointer, new TextRange(1, 5));
```