# Handle device loss with IDWriteTextLayout::SetDrawingEffect

Tags: directwrite

Following up on [How can I render mixed-colour text in DirectWrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656014/how-can-i-render-mixed-colour-text-in-directwrite), what's the best practice to handle device loss when passing a **device-dependent** resource — e.g. an `ID2D1LinearGradientBrush` or any other `ID2D1Brush` — as the first parameter of [`IDWriteTextLayout::SetDrawingEffect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritetextlayout-setdrawingeffect#syntax)?

To the best of my knowledge, I think `IDWriteTextLayout` was a **device-independent** resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing effect objects have no special meaning within DirectWrite. They are assigned for text ranges, and I believe do not break shaping - everything works normally, but then Draw() simply covers for different drawing effects by making several callback calls.

That means that lost device condition exists only at Direct2D side, and most likely you'll get in corresponding error state after DrawTextLayout() returns. When that happens, you'll need to recreate brushes, and set them again, no need to recreate layout objects.

Comment: Just call `SetDrawingEffect` again with re-created resources, then?

Comment: Sure. If you use the same text ranges, that will release previous effects, and addref new ones, i.e. you don't need to call SetDrawingEffect(NULL) explicitly.

Comment: To clarify, directwrite layout logic will simply pass effects pointers you set back to drawing callbacks, it won't interpret them in any way. That's Direct2D that has logic to check for effects being brushes, and if they are not Direct2D itself will ignore them. If you implement your own renderer, you can give effects any meaning you want.

Comment: _« If you use the same text ranges, that will release previous effects, and addref new ones »_ — Will it release effects for range `[a, b]` if I set another effect for range `[a-1, b+1]`? More generally, is there documentation about overlapping effects?

Comment: Yes, it will. Every text position can have only one effect pointer assigned to it, there is no overlapping.